# Calculate multiple composite scores in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a Python and Pandas newbie here and first ever Stackoverflow question.

I'm working with some survey data and need to create multiple composite scores. The problem I have is that there are 50 satisfaction scores and 50 importance scores and therefore I need to calculate 50 composite scores using the simple calculation: Comp1 = Sat1 * Imp1.

Here's an example DataFrame similar (shrunk down to just 5 metrics for simplicity) to the one I'm working with...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.random.randint(1,6, size=(6,10))
data = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Sat1', 'Sat2', 'Sat3', 'Sat4', 'Sat5', 'Imp1', 'Imp2', 'Imp3', 'Imp4', 'Imp5'])
print(data)
```

I then added new columns/series to my DF for my new composite variables...

```
comp = []
string = "Comp"
comp = [string+str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
data = pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(columns=list(comp))], axis=1)
print(data)
```

I know how to calculate one composite metric (series) at a time:

```
data['Comp1'] = data['Sat1'] * data['Imp1']
print(data)
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to iterate this calculations across the 50 metrics I have in my dataframe.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

Expected output:

```
  Sat1 Sat2Sat3Sat4Sat5Imp1Imp2Imp3Imp4Imp5Comp1Comp2Comp3Comp4Comp5
0   1   5   2   2   1   4   1   2   4   4   4   5   4   8   4
1   2   1   2   1   3   2   5   2   5   2   4   5   4   5   6
2   1   3   1   5   3   1   4   3   3   4   1   12  3   15  12
3   4   3   5   3   1   5   1   1   4   3   20  3   5   12  3
4   4   2   4   5   3   2   3   2   5   5   8   6   8   25  15
5   1   4   2   1   2   5   4   4   1   3   5   16  8   1   6
```

Comment: What is you expected output from this data?  Use np.random.seed(123) to fix random number generator for verifable outputs.

Comment: I've updated the post with the expected output

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, I think you do this:

```
data.join(data.groupby(data.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+\b)',expand=False), axis=1)
     .prod()
     .add_prefix('Comp'))
```

OR

```
(data.assign(**data.groupby(data.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+\b)',expand=False), axis=1)
     .prod()
     .add_prefix('Comp')))
```

Output:

```
   Sat1  Sat2  Sat3  Sat4  Sat5  Imp1  Imp2  Imp3  Imp4  Imp5  Comp1  Comp2  Comp3  Comp4  Comp5
0     3     5     3     2     4     3     4     2     2     1      9     20      6      4      4
1     2     2     1     1     2     4     5     1     1     5      8     10      1      1     10
2     2     4     3     5     3     5     1     1     2     4     10      4      3     10     12
3     5     5     5     2     4     3     2     5     1     4     15     10     25      2     16
4     3     1     4     3     3     3     3     5     4     4      9      3     20     12     12
5     5     5     4     3     1     5     4     2     4     3     25     20      8     12      3
```

First step:

```
data.groupby(data.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+\b)',expand=False), axis=1)\
    .prod()\
    .add_prefix('Comp')
```

Output:

```
   Comp1  Comp2  Comp3  Comp4  Comp5
0      9     20      6      4      4
1      8     10      1      1     10
2     10      4      3     10     12
3     15     10     25      2     16
4      9      3     20     12     12
5     25     20      8     12      3
```

Comment: The second option looks very nice !

Comment: @ryan If this answer helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Since your columns are in order, you can perform your calculation via extracted `numpy` arrays with no sorting:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.random.randint(1,6, size=(6,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Sat1', 'Sat2', 'Sat3', 'Sat4', 'Sat5', 'Imp1', 'Imp2', 'Imp3', 'Imp4', 'Imp5'])

cols = df.columns

sat = df[cols[cols.str.startswith('Sat')]].values
imp = df[cols[cols.str.startswith('Imp')]].values
comp = sat * imp

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(comp, columns=['Comp'+str(i) for i in range(1, comp.shape[1]+1)]))

#    Sat1  Sat2  Sat3  Sat4  Sat5  Imp1  Imp2  Imp3  Imp4  Imp5  Comp1  Comp2  \
# 0     1     4     1     3     4     3     1     3     5     1      3      4   
# 1     1     2     5     4     4     2     4     1     4     2      2      8   
# 2     3     4     5     1     3     5     4     1     4     1     15     16   
# 3     1     1     2     1     4     5     1     1     3     5      5      1   
# 4     2     4     5     4     1     3     4     2     4     1      6     16   
# 5     3     2     1     5     3     3     2     4     4     4      9      4   

#    Comp3  Comp4  Comp5  
# 0      3     15      4  
# 1      5     16      8  
# 2      5      4      3  
# 3      2      3     20  
# 4     10     16      1  
# 5      4     20     12
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.random.randint(1,6, size=(6,10))
data = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Sat1', 'Sat2', 'Sat3', 'Sat4', 'Sat5', 'Imp1', 'Imp2', 'Imp3', 'Imp4', 'Imp5'])

for i in range(1,6):
    data['Comp'+str(i)] = data['Sat'+str(i)].multiply(data['Imp'+str(i)])

print(data)
```